# Managing connections on a command based TCP socket API in node.js

Tags: api, node.js, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I built a RESTful API based on expresss.js which communicates to a remote server through a TCP socket using JSON. Requested URLs are converted into the appropriate JSON messages, a new TCP socket is open and the message is sent. Then when a message coming from the same connection is received an event is fired, the JSON reply is evaluated and a new JSON message is returned as the result of the GET request.

**Possible paths:**

1. Async (currently in use) - Open a connection to the server for each
   request.
2. Sync - Create a queue with all the requests and wait for
   the response, blocking code.
3. Track - Send all the request at once and asynchronously receive the answers. Use a tracker id on the request to relate each request with its answer.

**What will be the best direction to go? Is there any common pattern to solve this kind of application?**

Answer (score 1):

## 1 (async, a new connection for each request) is probably the easiest to implement.

If you want to reuse the socket for efficiently, you should come up with your own "keep-alive" mechanism - essentially streaming multiple requests and answers using the same socket.

I'd probably use double CRLF ('\n\r\n\r') as the delimiter of each JSON request, fire a 'request' event for each request, and simply write back the answer asynchronously. Delimiter-less streaming is possible, but it requires extra parsing when you receive a partial JSON string from the socket.